# Is it feasible to stream hexadecimal digits and output the stream in decimal without waiting for all the data to appear

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, radix

Say you have a file containing gigabytes worth of

```
deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
```

and you want to convert it to decimal, in the same way as you would 0xdeadbeef to 3,735,928,559.

Bases whose number is divisible by 2 are easy to do this with since you can operate on every few bits and output a number (6 for base64).

Any way to do this with decimal?

EDIT: The file represents one long number. The fact that it repeats itself is no different than the number 55,055,055,055.

EDIT2: The size of the file is known. What then?

Comment: Does the file represent a single number or a list of numbers?

Comment: If you have ONE number worth gigabytes of 0xAAAAA ... I wonder what would you do AFTER all the data appear

Comment: Do you know the size of the bit string in advance?  If not, you can't easily do this.

Comment: I am confident that this is possible, but doubtful that I can figure out how before someone else posts the answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can usually start writing before you're done reading the input. But if the number is very close to a power of ten, you might have to read more than half of the input before you can write the first digit of the output!

To see why, take a relatively small example. Suppose the number is 10<sup>60</sup>. The hex encoding for this is 50 hex digits. After reading the first 34 digits, you know this much:

```
9f4f2726179a224501d762422c946590d9................
```

The dots are the digits you haven't read yet.

At this point, you *still* can't write the first digit of the output, because the input could be anything from

```
9f4f2726179a224501d762422c946590d90000000000000000
```

to

```
9f4f2726179a224501d762422c946590d9ffffffffffffffff
```

And the former is decimal 999999999999999999999999999999999999999998847078495393153024, but the latter is 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000017293822569102704639. So you still don't know whether to write a 1 or a 9! Not until the 35th input digit can you start writing the output.

Generally, you'll have to read about three quarters of the input before writing the first output digit, in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong, wrong wrong. See comments.

<strike>Yes, but you have to work backwards (i.e. start from the end of the file).</strike>

1. Read the last digit.
2. Convert the digit to decimal, print it and store the most significant digit.
3. Read the next digit to the left.
4. Add the previous most significant digit, convert to decimal, print it and store the new most significant digit.
5. Repeat from step 3.

Edit: Added where the digits are printed. This produces the output decimal number in reverse (least significant digit first) order.

Comment: But will I be able to output something (through my stone chisling printer) before the full file is output?

Comment: Before the input or the output file is printed? You can chisel each digit as it's converted, but they'll be in reverse order (least significant digit first).

Comment: Suppose the input is `deadbeef`. Step 2 would print `5`, since 0xf is fifteen, right? But the number is actually 3735928559.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I neglected the rather obvious fact that the place values are different! Whoops, mea culpa. That'll teach me to post after meetings...

Comment: Just to clarify, this relies on the assumption that a digit doesn't interfere with the digits to the right of it, because when treated individually it will end in a bunch of zeros. That is of course not true for a different base. Sigh.